# Moment.js Deprecation (Not recognized ISO format

Tags: jquery, datatables, momentjs

Tengo un buscador de fechas en **dataTables** que por problemas de formatos utilizé la libreria **moment.js** y me funcionó todo perfecto, ahora bien, cuando he querido guardar dichas búsquedas en sesión para que los inputs no pierdan los valores me ha empezado a fallar, aunque no del todo.

El caso es que tengo una view con dos tablas una al lado de otra, y tengo un buscador de intervalo de fechas, si solo lo uso en uno, me funciona perfectamente, ahora en el momento que recargo página después de buscar en ambas al momento de recargar me sale el siguiente error:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 0.00, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js:20:668)
    at eb (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js:132:129)
    at pb (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js:172:413)
    at ob (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js:172:274)
    at nb (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js:170:503)
    at qb (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js:177:164)
    at rb (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js:177:198)
    at q.Zb [as isSame] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js:233:774)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://project.local/tables:87290:55)
    at yb (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:43:117)
```

Ambos inputs, variables de sesión son distintas para cada tabla, por lo que debería funcionar si funcionan por separado y con funciones separadas.

Alguien se ha encontrado este error alguna vez? He mirado la documentación oficial pero no da mucha luz al respecto.

**EDITO:**

He encontrado la manera de parametrizar la función que hace que me falle el moment.js o eso me pienso. Pero claro al poner el **settings.nTable.id** para saber a que tabla debe filtrar, me sale un error **Uncaught ReferenceError: settings is no defined**

Aquí dejo el ejemplo que he encotrado en la web oficial de **DataTables**

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( settings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
   if ( settings.nTable.id === 'example' ) {
      // filter example
   } else {
      // ...
   }
  }
);
```

Buscando en la documentación y por todos lados no he encontrado nada haciendo referencia a como se declara dicho **settings** alguien sabría decirme algo sobre dicha funcionalidad?

Comment: He encontrado esta web donde uno comenta el mismo error pero con otro caso, he probado y a mi no me funciona. Alguien sabe algo al respecto?

https://webdesignersdairy.blogspot.com.es/2016/08/deprecation-warning-moment-construction.html

Comment: Podrias agregar tu codigo javascript

Answer (score 1):

La cosa es que para la versión **1.10** de **DataTables** han cambiado la API por lo que ahora en lugar de:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( settings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
   if ( settings.nTable.id === 'example' ) {
      // filter example
   } else {
      // ...
   }
  }
);
```

Ahora la función tiene otro nombre:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( settings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
   if ( oSettings.nTable.id === 'example' ) {
      // filter example
   } else {
      // ...
   }
  }
);
```

Lo mismo pasa con la funcion **.draw()** que ahora es **.fnDraw()**